# Regex to detect text symbols in single quotes

Tags: regex, text, quotes, symbols

Please, I need you to help me with the next assignment.

I need to create a regular expression that allows me to get all text in single quotes that have symbols.

I am using the following expression: **[^a-zA-Z0-9]*** for symbols, but I have two days trying to get only the texts with symbols that are in single quotes and have not succeeded.

Example:

**'c$$ $$ _ da'** my **'name'** is Angel and my **'phone'** is 555-5555-555 and ends with this text **'avv%% 2'**.

I need to detect: **'c$$ $$ _ da'** and **'avv%% 2'**.

You can use PCRE or other standard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `_` and space considered symbol?

Comment: @rock321987 probably given the text string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best attempt:

```
/'[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*?(:?[^a-zA-Z0-9\s']+?[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*?)+?'(?=\W|$)/g
```

You can see it in action [here](http://www.regexr.com/3dthj).